# Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'int' - Substracting datasets

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, timestamp

I have the following datasets:

1) Dataset with Month as TimeStamp

```
df = pd.DataFrame(residuals, columns = ['Passengers'])
```

```
             Passengers
Month   
1949-01-01  -0.082329
1949-02-01  -0.040724
1949-03-01  0.060813
1949-04-01  0.027243
1949-05-01  -0.047359
1949-06-01  0.051545
1949-07-01  0.132902
1949-08-01  0.122322
```

b) Dataset with Month as Int

```
dz = pd.DataFrame(estacionalitat, columns = ['Passengers'])
```

```
    Passengers
Month   
1   -0.075844
2   -0.089111
3   0.042705
4   0.002147
5   -0.010528
6   0.109443
7   0.198334
8   0.209830
```

A set oftransformations have been carried out in both datasets but originally data comes from the following dataset:

```
data = pd.read_csv('AirPassengers.csv', parse_dates=['Month'], index_col='Month', header=0)
```

I would like to subtract one dataset as from the other as follows:

```
df-dz
```

However, when I try to do the above I get the following message:

**Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'int'**

I guess this is because 'Month' is of type int in one dataset while in the other is of type Date. Furthermore,  I don´t know how to access 'Month' because it is not understood as a column.

Comment: You can access month with `data.index`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If want convert `DatetimeIndex` to months use:

```
df.index = df.index.month
```

Then get integers in both, columns names are same, so possible subtract:

```
df = df-dz
print (df)
       Passengers
Month            
1       -0.006485
2        0.048387
3        0.018108
4        0.025096
5       -0.036831
6       -0.057898
7       -0.065432
8       -0.087508
```

Comment: When I do what you have recently written I get the following error: 
AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'month'

Comment: @Panri93 - Try `df = df.set_index('Month')` before my solution

Comment: Now I get  KeyError: 'Month'. I have checked the index as well. See: Int64Index([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10,
            ...
             3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12],
           dtype='int64', name='Month'

Comment: @Panri93 - `df` is first DataFrame, there is no `DatetimeIndex` ?

Comment: df in itself does not contain any DateTimeIndex, however, I checked 'residuals' and yes it has a DateTimeIndex. I have applied what you said with 'residuals' and I get another error - AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'set_index'

Comment: @Panri93 - if DatetimeIndex then `df = df.set_index('Month')` is not necessary ;)